# Understanding mysql memory consumption

Tags: mysql, memory

I want to understand memory being consumed by particular blob column in my sql table.

I have a table STUDENT with field DATA of medium blob type. I have already fetched total length of blob column:

```
 select sum(length(DATA)) from STUDENT;
 result is : 922358752
```

What I don't understand is how to get memory consumed by this blob in MB?

Comment: So you mean memory consumed is 922358752+2 bytes?

Comment: Your question itself isn't clear. Do you mean memory used by your app when it reads in the blob or the __storage__ taken by the blob when it's stored in the database?

Comment: I meant storage taken by blob when its stored in database. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Well that's what the dup target gives you

Answer (score 0):

You are using `SUM()`, so your result is, well, the sum of the length of all the `DATA` columns in your `STUDENT` table. In bytes.

Ordinarily, you get kilobytes by dividing bytes by 1024. You get megabytes by dividing kilobytes by 1024. You get gigabytes by.... you get the idea.

MySQL stores extra stuff in its disk files. Some of that extra stuff is predictable. For example, each medium blob column uses three extra bytes. See this:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html

Your `SUM()` result does not include those extra three bytes.  If you want to include them you'll need

```
select sum(length(DATA)) + 3 * count(DATA) from STUDENT;
```

or

```
 select sum(length(DATA) + 3) from STUDENT;
```

You can probably get a nice display of the megabytes like this

```
 select ROUND(sum(length(DATA) + 3)/(1024.0*1024.0), 2) from STUDENT;
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, I got it. It wasn't clear to me what exactly length(DATA) represents.